# Reading from data table gets a Factor not a double

Tags: r

I am not sure if I am providing sufficient information, but if I am not, please tell me.

I loaded a data frame from a CSV file with columns of integers and a column, `c`, with doubles. Let's call this data frame `tb`.

Now I want to extract the particular double from the data table `tb`. However, when I key in something like

```
print(tb[4,][['c']]);
```

it gives me a response like

```
[1] 790.000000000001
92 Levels: -730.33000000000001 -290.0 -912.47 -37.8000000000000089 -291.780000000000002     
... null
```

I tried something different like getting just the row and printing it. There are no problems. However, in the environment, it records it with something like `Factor w/ 92 levels`...

I have been checking online for resources but to no avail. Not sure if this is anomaly behaviour on my own machine or not.

### Update

I used `read.csv` as follows:

```
tb <- read.csv(file="test_3.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",");
```

Sure, some rows of the csv files are as follows:

```
a,b,c,d
1,170,771.8,1170.0
1,1,1.87,76.0
1,76,345.04,0.0
1,102,463.08,566.0
4,188,1530.3200000000002,3548.0000000000005
```

#### Epilogue

My csv file had rows like this
    4,188,null,3548.0000000000005

Hence reading the file gave problems. Using the `na.strings=("null")` command at the `read.csv` worked wonders.

Comment: Are you using `read.csv2` or `read.csv`?

Comment: `read.csv`. I updated the question.

Comment: So additionally please provide a few rows of the csv. file. BTW, you may do `tb[4,] <- as.numeric(as.character(tb[4,]))`

Comment: sure, i updated the question with a few rows of the csv

Comment: @bryansis2010 Does the sample actually reproduce your problem? If sounds like you have at least one value in that column that is non numeric. Does anything come up when you rin `tb$d[is.null(as.numeric(as.character(tb$d))]`

Comment: @MrFlick I have scanned my file. It does say that some rows have the "null" word. Hence, what do i do? Indeed, there was some kind of datatype mismatch

Comment: You can substitute `NULL` for `NA` text, it should be read as missing data then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a non-numeric value somewhere in that column. You can find it with

```
tb$d[is.null(as.numeric(as.character(tb$d))]
```

If it's something like "null", you can automatically convert those values to proper missing values in R with the `na.strings` parameter

```
read.csv(..., na.strings="null")
```

when you read in the data.